# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo caused by onClickListener

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following error when I reboot my device (my app launches on boot, as it is defined as a launcher). This only started happening recently for some odd reason!

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.domain.application/com.domain.application.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

The Exception in LogCat points to:

```
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
// code here to deal with button press
}
```

*loginBtn* is defined near the start of the *onCreate*:

```
// Set activity view
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Initialise button
Button loginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
```

The activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="#000000">

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/screen"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pw"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pw"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have searched through nearly all the instances of this error on SO, and I have double checked everything and I'm sure my code is correct.

Like I said, this has only just started happening and only happens when the device boots.

If I debug the app (so it re-installs and starts) it is fine, there is no error.

Manifest XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.domain.application"
      android:versionCode="16"
      android:versionName="1.1.5" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
        <!--<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PlaylistActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".WebViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="Boot completed">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".PlaylistService" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you put your AndroidManifest file ?

Comment: is it normal using two intent-filters ?

Comment: One is commented out

Comment: did you check your imports especially the R class ?

Comment: can you also add your loginBtn.setOnClickListener code ?

Comment: Pretty certain the code inside the login button is fine (the error message pointed to the line where the onclicklistener is defined, also the code is quite sensitive in nature). How d I check the imports? There are no errors shown in Android Studio regarding the button IDs

Comment: post your complete logcat, also uncomment `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`